# Two approvals for suggested edits

Tags: support, editing, suggested-edits

It seems to me that currently a suggested edit needs two approval (or reject) reviews (as suggested edits on Stack Overflow) while a week ago they required only one approval/reject. Why? What is behind the change?

Comment: I have no idea what is the reason, but according to [the history of suggested edits](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/history), this was changed on 16 October.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, [suggested edits require two reviews](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/151586/162704) since the 16<sup>th</sup>:

> In response to [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137784/what-can-we-do-to-stop-bad-edits-getting-accepted), we've bumped up the number of reviews required to approve or reject a suggested edit:
>
> - **Network-wide:** two reviews per edit suggestion.
> - **Stack Overflow:** three reviews per edit suggestion.
>
> Moderators can approve suggested edits instantly in cases where an insufficient number of users are available to review them.